# Retrieving models without getting associated models - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I use the find('all') function to  retrieve the post records from my database, but this will also return all the User information that is  associated with the Post model with a belongsTo - hasMany relationship.

The downside of this is that the user model contains password and other important information. Is this considered a security issue? I am nowhere echo-ing the information on the view.

Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

I modified my code but I am still getting the associated models.

```
        $this->set('posts_list',$this->Post->find('all',array('contain' => false, 'order' => array('Post.price ASC'))));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have several options. You can set the `recursive` property on a model:

```
$this->Post->recursive = -1;
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
```

Alterantively, you can specify `recursive` as an option to your search:

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'conditions' => ...
);
```

You can also use the `Containable` behaviour in your Post model. In that case you can specify an empty set:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}

$this->Post->contain();
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
```

Or, specified in the query:

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'contain' => false,
);
```

The upside for the `Containable` behaviour is when you later on associate other models with your post. Suppose that you implement a Tag model. Now you want to find a post with it's tags, but not the use model:

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Tag'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the 'contain' => false method, but it still returns the associated model for some reason. Check out the edit for my code

Comment: Did you include the `Containable` behaviour in your model? See my edit above.

Comment: I was missing that... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Brilliant work it saves my hour. Thanks its a perfect approach.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily.

But you are retrieving information when you don't need it. It's not a problem now, but keep in mind this becomes a huge problem when you have a lot of associated data

Consider setting your `recursive` attribute to `-1` (or 0 if needed)

```
$this->Model->recursive = -1;
```

This will pull data only from the selected model

Or for more fine tuned selection, you can use the Containable behavior : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

This allows you to select which associations to keep when retrieving data.

Answer (score 3):

just so you know

```
$this->Model->recursive = -1 will remove all associations
$this->Model->recursive = 0 will remove only hasMany assosiation (so it keeps belongsTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do u use this:

```
$this->Post->find('all')// If u access it from Post controller
```

OR,

```
$this->User->Post->find('all')//If u access it from User controller
```